# OMNET++:cannot import openflow extension into veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

i want to import openflow extension into veins, when i run openflow simulation it works correctly, but when start veins simulation I receive the error:

`Class "Flow_Table" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().`

[image]

Comment: i edited my question , i want to import openflow extension into veins, when i run openflow simulation it works correctly, but when start veins simulation I receive the error:

**Class "Flow_Table" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().**

can anyone help me?

Comment: sorry, but where could i check command line??

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation will need to load the libraries (on Windows: `.dll` files, on Linux: `.so` files) which contain the simulation modules you are using.

Check the command line used to run your simulation (likely it starts with `opp_run`). If it does not contain a `-l` switch for the OpenFlow simulation library, you will not be able to create its modules in your simulation.

If you use the OMNeT++ IDE to start your simulation, look at the very top of the Console window to see which command line parameters were used. For example, in the following screenshot you can see that only `-l ../../src/veins` is specified; thus, only modules from `libveins.so` are loaded.

[image]